# unable to retrieve contents on left join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

i have a table loan_repayed with following data

```
l_id   i_no  dif     interval   amt
===================================  
32     33   735      3        27774
32     34   707      3        27774
32     35   676      3        27774
```

i have other table interval with following data

```
id  min max
============
1   30   60
2   60   90
3   90   9999
```

when i execute the below query

```
 select 
    lpt.l_Id, 
    d.id, 
    ifnull(sum(lpt.amt),0) 
 from 
     loan_repayed lpt 
 left join 
     interval d on lpt.interval = d.id 
 where 
     lpt.loan_id = 32
 group by 
     lpt.l_id, d.id;
```

iam expecting to get

```
   l_id      interval   amt
   =========================
    32       1           0
    32       2           0
    32       3           83322
```

but iam getting oly 1 row

```
 l_id      interval     amt
 ===========================
   32        3         333298
```

where am i going wrong could anybody suggest .... thank u

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(lpt.l_id, 32) AS L_ID, 
  d.id, 
  IFNULL(SUM(lpt.amt),0) 
FROM `interval` AS d 
LEFT JOIN loan_repayed AS lpt ON lpt.interval = d.id 
GROUP BY lpt.l_id, d.id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8ab8/10).

---

### UPDATE 1

For multiple values you can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  d.l_id,
  d.id,
  IFNULL(l.totalamt, 0) AS totalamt
FROM
(
  SELECT l.l_id, d.id
  from 
  (             -- <---------- here you list the values you want
    SELECT 32 AS L_ID
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 32
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 33
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 34
  ) AS l CROSS JOIN(SELECT id from `interval`) as d
) AS d
LEFT JOIN
(
select 
    lpt.L_ID, 
    d.id, 
    ifnull(sum(lpt.amt),0) AS totalamt
 from `interval` AS d
 INNER JOIN loan_repayed lpt on lpt.interval = d.id 
group by lpt.l_id, d.id
) AS l ON l.l_id = d.l_id AND d.id = l.id ;
```

### [Updated SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8ab8/57)

This will give you:

```
| L_ID | ID | TOTALAMT |
------------------------
|   32 |  1 |        0 |
|   32 |  2 |        0 |
|   32 |  3 |    83322 |
|   33 |  1 |        0 |
|   33 |  2 |        0 |
|   33 |  3 |        0 |
|   34 |  1 |        0 |
|   34 |  2 |        0 |
|   34 |  3 |        0 |
```

Comment: @Santosh What do you mean? Where does these different `l_id`'s coming from? The problem is that, you have to `LEFT JOIN` the interval values so that you can get all the id from that column, but there is no corresponding `l_id` from the other table, that why I put `32` or `IFNULL(lpt.l_id, 32) AS L_ID`. In case there are different `l_id` where are these ids coming from?

Comment: basically loan_repayed is temporory table in stored procedure.... wen i insert data into it, iam comparing diff column with min and max of interval table and appropriate id is inserted along.....i have different l_id's in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select lpt.l_Id, d.id, ifnull(sum(lpt.amt),0) from 
 loan_repayed lpt left join interval d on lpt.interval = d.id 
 where lpt.loan_id = 32
 group by d.id,lpt.l_id;
```

or.. use `having` instead of `where`

```
select lpt.l_Id, d.id, ifnull(sum(lpt.amt),0) from
loan_repayed lpt left join interval d on lpt.interval = d.id
group by d.id,lpt.l_id having lpt.loan_id = 32;
```

Comment: if i have multiple l_id's like 32,33,34... etc